# Failed to minify the code ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/es/styles/createMuiTheme.js

Tags: material-ui

Hey i i am working with the latest version of material UI, i have a problem when i am trying to create build (react-scripts build).
this is the error that i got:

```html
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file: 

  ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/es/styles/createMuiTheme.js:17
```

i didn't found any solution for my problem. i am using createMuiTheme for override some components.
thank you very much.

Comment: Could you show us the component for which you override the styles and the way you import `createMuiTheme`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error with material-ui that occurs when you import a component with `/es` in the path.

Search on your code if at some point you import `createMuiTheme`. You most likely import it from `@material-ui/core/es/styles...`, instead, import it this way:

`import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`